# Intellij - Hide file paths from Favorites window

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

I organized my project files in the Favourites window according to the programming language e.g. python, javascript etc. However, the path to each file takes a lot of space and requires you to horizontaly scroll the window.

Is there a way to hide path from the Favourites, so only file names are visible? If not, is there a way to organize files in the same way without changing the project structure?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screen shot to show what you mean?

Comment: *"...and requires you to vertically scroll.."* You mean "horizontally" ? I see no way how such paths would affect vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to hide those paths.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4374 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

*Please note that the aforementioned ticket is in "Backlog" section -- such tickets are unlikely to be implemented in nearest future (especially if they have virtually no votes).*